# Oracle APEX - numeric value error in a filter

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an Oracle APEX application. It has a numeric column, and the default filter setup will allow the user to enter any text in the filter value. This results in a server-side error, which is not very user friendly.
Is there any way to restrict the values entered in the filter to numeric only values?

Answer (score 0):

Did you set item's type to "Number field"? Help says

> Displays a number field. This item type automatically validates that the value is a number.

---

Or, you could use "Text field" as its type and create a validation. For example, a function body that returns error text:

```
if not regexp_like (:P1_THAT_ITEM, '^\d+$') then
   return 'Enter a number';
end if;
```

Comment: The item is set to number. If the user chooses filter values from a drop down, then the suggestions are all numbers. It is just that they are not stopped from entering arbitrary text. I'd rather not make it a text field as that seems like it might cause even more problems down the line.

Comment: Well, validation will do in any case; item type shouldn't matter. I used "Text field" because it lets you choose "Submit when Enter pressed" which then runs validation.

Comment: It's only really the filtering that's an issue, I don't want the user to add new values.